# How to click the link located in a list using Selenium WebDriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

[I want to click the "Next" link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq2ST.jpg)

Hi! I've been trying to scrape data for some project I have. I'm still new at using Selenium but I've been able to do the basics. What I want to do now is for the program to click the "Next" link above to move to the next page to scrape more data. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li.ng-scope[translate='next']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'ng-scope') and @translate='next'][contains(.,'Next')]"))).click();
  ```